# Why not 1 CPU core in place of multiple cores?

Tags: ram, cpu-registers, cpu-cache, cpu-cores

I've just read something about how CPU cores interact with each other. I can be wrong on some points so don't hesitate to correct me.

So a CPU will basically run instructions that are stored in the L2 or L3 cache. These instructions are addresses that reference to an object in the DRAM.

A multi-core CPU will be able to run more instructions, this will result in better performance. But there is a little problem with that: these cores have to interact with each other, and this is slowing down a little bit the process.

So now that I go back to my question: Why do we not use 1 CPU with bigger cache? As I think, this should give more performance for less costs? Right?

I know these are some basic things that you should know lol. I feel a little bit weird asking this.

Any answer would be welcome!

Comment: You're forgetting the speed of these hypothetical cpu's... just imagine this: a single core 20GHz processor vs a 10 core 2GHz processor...

Answer (score 0):

Multiple cores means you have duplicated circuitry which allow you to do more work in parallel. Each core has its own L1 dcache and icache along with their own registers, decode units, execution pipelines etc.

Just having a bigger cache and a 20 ghz clock won't give you as much performance because you still have to share all other resources.

Answer (score -1):

As someone said to me, I'm forgetting clock speed of CPU's.

## LOL

Just Imagine a single core 20GHz; the refresh rate would be too fast to interact with the RAM.  In other terms, that means that too much data would be lost, which would result in a crash.
Same holds true with overclocking. -_-

Comment: Already with present CPU's there's a massive mismatch between memory speed and cpu speed, and it's no reason for a crash, just for increasing inefficiency. Multicores allow sockets to deliver performance that are technologically or physically unattainable with 1 core.

Comment: Plus, most computers need to do multiple tasks at the same time, a problem that can be solved by ever-faster timeslicing (with increasing inefficiency) or by more cores (less taskswitching needed without the loss of responsiveness)